# Get the second max value grouping by id

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the records:

```
ID | Value
 1 |   999
 1 |   005
 1 |   001
 2 |   003
 2 |   999
 3 |   999
 3 |   999
```

I need to get the max value if different of 999 else get the 999, example of result:

```
ID | Value
 1 |   005
 2 |   003
 3 |   999
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your requirement, create a table

```
Create Table dbo.tblMaxVal(id int,value int)
```

Insert your data into table  and here an example

```
Select m.id,min(m.value) as value from ( 
Select distinct t.id,Max(t.value) as Value  from dbo.tblMaxVal t where t.value < (  
Select v.val as value from ( 
Select id,Max(value) as val from dbo.tblMaxVal group by id  order by id ) as v  where v.id=t.id  ) group by t.id 
union
Select  id, Max(value)  from dbo.tblMaxVal  group by id  ) m group by m.id
```

I know this is not ideal query but maybe this query helpful  for you to understand what you need.

Result -

```
id | value
1  | 005
2  | 003
3  | 999
```